# How to calculate time difference between start time and end time?

Tags: mysql

Here is the query which i have tried.. Don't know why it is not working..

SELECT function_code,start_time,end_time,TIMEDIFF('end_time','start_time') ,total_units FROM function

[image]

Comment: Elaborate  your problem, What error are you getting with this approach?

Comment: I just want to find the time difference between start time and end time in mysql table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT function_code,start_time,end_time,TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time) ,total_units FROM function
```

This should work as you have used single quote for `end_time` and `start_time`, `TIMEDIFF` function considered it as time not the columns hence your output is not coming what you expected.